# ¿Cómo puedo centrar una imagen dentro de un div dentro de un ion-slide-box?

Tags: html, css, ionic

Estoy tratando de centrar una imágen dentro de un `div` dentro de un `ion-slide-box` de la siguiente forma

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)"
                auto-play="true"
                slide-interval="2000"
                does-continue="true"
                show-pager="false"
                style="height: 200px !important;">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="image in images">
            <div style="text-align: center; width: 300px;">
                <img ng-src="{{ image.src }}" style="width: 100%; text-align: center !important;"/>
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>
```

El resultado es este, he intentado de todo un poco mediante `css` pero no logro obtener mi resultado deseado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has intentado con flex?

Comment: @x-rw ¿flex? ¿me podrías facilitar algún link?

Comment: en el sitio de ingles hay tutoriales, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/445/flexible-box-layout-flexbox#t=201702071501056735462

Comment: ¿Podrías facilitarnos un ejemplo que podamos reproducir? Puedes insertar el código en tu pregunta pulsando Cntrl+M.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes utilizar esto en tu CSS

```
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

y en tu imagen lo siguiente

```
<img ng-src="{{ image.src }}" class="center"/>
```

De esta manera no es necesario ajustar cada imagen por sí misma y eso me parece muy descriptiva, cuando nos fijamos en el código HTML. Además, no se limita a un tamaño específico de la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma es en tu div y flex box

```
.container-img{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

y en tu div

```
<div class="container-img">
<img src={{img.src}} alt="Nuevo Diseño">
</div>
```